# How to restore Ubuntu data after install windows 7?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I have installed windows 7. I have lost my all data which were in ubuntu. Now want to get my all previous data. I have installed windows 7 in other partition. Ubuntu partition lost all data if it is possible that I restore Ubuntu please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Windows on another partition (and not formated your Ubuntu partition), you should be able to boot a live-cd and reinstall the boot loader (grub) from there - you can find tutorials for "grub reinstall" online.
This looks good, actually:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair